# Next steps after exploiting blind SQL injection

Tags: php, penetration-test, sql-injection, apache, mysql

I have discovered a web form that accepts an email and promo code, and if the code is valid, you would receive an in-game gift. Unfortunately, I had no promo codes, however I've found this form to contain SQL injection vulnerabilities on both fields.

***Disclaimer:*** After discovering the initial vulnerability I had reported it to server owner and asked for the permission to poke around, so he granted the permission to me and removed the vulnerable form from public access.

I have managed to reconstruct remote logic (in pseudocode):

```
handle(code, email) {
    cursor = `SELECT type, date FROM codes WHERE code='${code}' LIMIT 1`;

    if (cursor.rows != 0) {
        `INSERT INTO codes
         (code, type, email, date)
         VALUES ('already_used', 0, '${email}', NOW())`;

        return 'Error: promo code has already been used';
    }

    if (cursor.date != NULL) {
        `INSERT INTO codes
         (code, type, email, date)
         VALUES ('invalid', 0, '${email}', NOW())`;

        return 'Error: invalid promo code';
    }

    `UPDATE codes SET email='${email}', date=NOW() WHERE code='${code}'`;

    if (cursor.type == 2) {
        send_mail(to=email, "<html>You have used promo ${code}, but the cake is a lie.</html>");
    }

    return 'HUGE SUCCESS! You will now get a cake.';
}
```

And the schema of `codes` table is seemingly as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE codes (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    code CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    type INT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(256),
    date DATETIME
);
```

Injection into `code` field is blind — so I can check whether SQL `expr` is true ("already used promo") or false ("invalid promo"). I am using `' OR (${expr}) #` vector.

I have expanded this channel to allow passing string results out. First I detect result length via `' OR ((${expr}) REGEXP '^.{N,}') #` checks, using binary search to find proper `N`. Then I reveal the result char by char using range queries like `' OR (CONVERT((${expr}) USING BINARY) REGEXP '^id[[.comma.]][f-k]') #` via binary search for each char.

This way I've learned the `VERSION()` (MySQL 5.1.73-cll), exact schema of `codes` table via `information_schema` introspection, names of other databases etc. I don't have `FILE` permission, so I cannot use `LOAD_FILE()`.

Exploiting injection in `email` field, I have managed to register a new promo code via `', NOW()), ('fake-promo', 2, NULL, NULL) #` vector.

Because warnings were not suppressed, I know the absolute path to PHP script that handles these requests. Unfortunately, as I lack `FILE` permission, I don't know the way to get its source. From warnings I can also tell that script uses obsolete `mysql_query()` and `mysql_num_rows()` APIs.

Script sends emails that have `X-Source-Args` and `X-Source-Dir` headers set (and PHP seems to run under apache2), so I can conclude that emails are sent via PHP `mail()` function.

---

So, what are my further steps in exploring the system?

I am suggesting that `mail` might be exploitable with some sort of shell injection via forged recipient `email`, however I am not sure where to start from.

Also, any other attack vectors maybe? Making `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` possible on arbitrary tables? Breaking out of my one-bit communication channel? Reading the source of PHP script?

Comment: Thanks for this description! I am fairly new to this topic and your thread helped me out quite a lot

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you explored this one pretty well. But pentesting means enumeration, enumeration, enumeration. So if you want to go deeper you should also try to find out everything you can around other potential attack vectors. Web server paths and the like. Maybe you find an admin logon page. Can you fully enumerate the db? What about user tables and passwords?

That said, you wouldn't be the first one who can't turn a SQL injection vuln into a reverse shell. If you can fully enumerate the DB that is already a pretty significant breach of the target.